# MS access validation rule violation insert query

Tags: ms-access

I have a situation where I have to copy a bunch of values form one table to another table. I am trying to use an INSERT query to achieve this goal

```
Insert INTO Table1 (ID,Qty)
Select ID,Qty from Table2
```

I pulled table2 from an excel spreadsheet. I made sure that every field property like field size, format, required, indexed etc matches for both fields but I am still getting the validation rule violation error.

I also tried to Insert only the ID or quantity field but I get the same error for both of them.

Comment: Not enough information shared.  It isn't sufficient to just say that you have checked the field properties, etc.  You need to include those details if 1) you are having problems that you can't resolve and 2) are asking others to help solve the problem.  There is apparently something that you're overlooking, but we can't help if we can't see the schema detail.  It's also best to include the exact text of an error rather than just paraphrasing the error.  You should inspect the table-level validation rule property.  Is ID an auto-increment field, since those don't normally support inserts?

Comment: It is possible to insert value in autonumber ID field with INSERT action sql. However this messes up the seed and must run compact & repair to fix before allowing any other data input. Of course, if the ID value is already in the destination table, the duplicate will be rejected.

Comment: Does Table1 contain only those 2 fields?  If not, is there a field which does not allow Null and does not have a default value defined?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for this. I feel so dumb for not thinking about this. There was a field in Table 1 which had required property set to yes